# Failed to install Visual Studio for Mac Preview on macOS Sierra

Tags: android-studio, xamarin, xamarin-studio, visual-studio-mac

On **macOS Sierra 10.12.2** the Visual Studio for Mac Preview fails to install. The install version is **3.0.0.** (1).

The software requirements are all installed, but the installer fails to detect the Android SDK at some point:

```
[2017-01-12 10:08:52.260] [Debug] Detecting software item 'Mono Framework'
[2017-01-12 10:08:52.260] [Info] Checking whether Mono needs update/installation
[2017-01-12 10:08:52.260] [Debug] In IsCurrentMonoNewEnough
[2017-01-12 10:08:52.260] [Debug] current == /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current
[2017-01-12 10:08:52.260] [Debug] current symlink: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.6.2
[2017-01-12 10:08:52.260] [Debug] file name: 4.6.2
[2017-01-12 10:08:52.261] [Debug] parsed version: 4.6.2
[2017-01-12 10:08:52.261] [Info] Mono 4.8.0 needs to be installed.
[2017-01-12 10:08:52.362] [Info] Status: successful
[2017-01-12 10:08:52.362] [Info] Software item 'Mono Framework': not up to date
[2017-01-12 10:08:52.368] [Info] Component 'Mono Framework' v. 4.8.0 absent
[2017-01-12 10:08:52.369] [Debug] Component Mono Framework enqueuing URL https://dl.xamarin.com/MonoFrameworkMDK/Macx86/MonoFramework-MDK-4.8.0.344.macos10.xamarin.universal.pkg
[2017-01-12 10:08:53.506] [Debug] Detecting software item 'Java SDK'
[2017-01-12 10:08:53.507] [Info] Checking whether Oracle JDK needs update/installation
[2017-01-12 10:08:53.509] [Info] Status: successful
[2017-01-12 10:08:53.509] [Info] Component 'Java SDK' v. 1.8.0 1.8.0 present
[2017-01-12 10:08:53.509] [Info] Software item 'Java SDK': up to date
[2017-01-12 10:08:53.509] [Debug] Detecting software item 'Android SDK'
[2017-01-12 10:08:53.509] [Info] Checking if Android SDK needs to be updated/installed
[2017-01-12 10:08:53.510] [Info] Using default samples:
[2017-01-12 10:08:53.510] [Info] Downloading from 'http://download.xamarin.com/Installer/xamarin-android-sdk.xml'.
[2017-01-12 10:08:53.510] [Debug] Setting download timeout for 'http://download.xamarin.com/Installer/xamarin-android-sdk.xml' to 60s
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.229] [Warning] Cannot map element 'lldb' to descriptor type.
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.229] [Warning] Cannot map element 'lldb' to descriptor type.
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.231] [Warning] Cannot map element 'lldb' to descriptor type.
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.231] [Warning] Cannot map element 'lldb' to descriptor type.
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.232] [Warning] Cannot map element 'licenses' to descriptor type.
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.433] [Debug] Detecting Android SDK in '/Users/loretoparisi/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx'
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.538] [Debug] Download size for 'http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r13b-darwin-x86_64.zip': 665967997
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.538] [Debug] NDK found in '/Users/loretoparisi/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-ndk/android-ndk-r13b', no update necessary
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.538] [Error] Failed to find archive for component 'system-image---default'. Tried any:any:64, any:any:0
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.538] [Error] Android component 'system-image-23-armeabi-v7a-default': archive for OS any and architecture any not found in the manifest
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.538] [Exception] Attempt to initialize component 'system-image-23-armeabi-v7a-default' failed
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.538] [Exception] System.InvalidOperationException: No suitable component archive found.
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.538] [Exception] at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidComponentBase.Init (Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidComponentDescriptorBase descriptor, System.Uri repositoryUrl) [0x0011f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4029/b49471af/source/installer/Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK/Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK/AndroidComponentBase.cs:299
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.538] [Exception] at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidComponentSystemImage.Init (Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidComponentDescriptorBase descriptor, System.Uri repositoryUrl) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4029/b49471af/source/installer/Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK/Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK/AndroidComponentSystemImage.cs:36
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.538] [Exception] at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidComponentDescriptorBase.CreateComponent (System.String baseDownloadUrl, Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidSDKInstaller installer) [0x00075] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4029/b49471af/source/installer/Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK/Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK/AndroidComponentDescriptorBase.cs:196
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.538] [Info] Status: failed.
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.538] [Exception] Failed to detect component 'Android SDK'
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.538] [Exception] System.InvalidOperationException: No suitable component archive found.
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.538] [Exception] at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidComponentBase.Init (Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidComponentDescriptorBase descriptor, System.Uri repositoryUrl) [0x0011f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4029/b49471af/source/installer/Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK/Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK/AndroidComponentBase.cs:299
```

Looking at logs it seems that that the Android SDK and NKD are firstly detected in the default folder, but then something fails.

I have both Xamarin Studio Community Edition installed and Android Studio installed, so all required components should be satisfied.

The error log continues

```
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.538] [Exception] Failed to detect component 'Android SDK'
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.538] [Exception] System.InvalidOperationException: No suitable component archive found.
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.538] [Exception] at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidComponentBase.Init (Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidComponentDescriptorBase descriptor, System.Uri repositoryUrl) [0x0011f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4029/b49471af/source/installer/Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK/Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK/AndroidComponentBase.cs:299
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.538] [Exception] at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidComponentSystemImage.Init (Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidComponentDescriptorBase descriptor, System.Uri repositoryUrl) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4029/b49471af/source/installer/Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK/Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK/AndroidComponentSystemImage.cs:36
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.538] [Exception] at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidComponentDescriptorBase.CreateComponent (System.String baseDownloadUrl, Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidSDKInstaller installer) [0x00075] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4029/b49471af/source/installer/Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK/Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK/AndroidComponentDescriptorBase.cs:196
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.538] [Exception] Detection failed for task Android SDK.
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.538] [Exception] System.InvalidOperationException: No suitable component archive found.
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.538] [Exception] at Xamarin.Web.Installer.TasksManager.DetectComponents () [0x00097] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4029/b49471af/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/TasksManager.cs:297
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.539] [Info] Status: failed.
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.539] [Exception] Initial task interrupted by exception
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.539] [Exception] System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: No suitable component archive found.
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.539] [Exception] at Xamarin.Web.Installer.TasksManager.DetectComponents () [0x00097] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4029/b49471af/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/TasksManager.cs:297
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.539] [Exception] --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.539] [Exception] at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00014] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/2.10.0.113/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2157
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.539] [Exception] at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00052] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/2.10.0.113/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:3189
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.539] [Exception] at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/2.10.0.113/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:3107
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.539] [Exception] at Xamarin.Web.Installer.TasksManager.WaitForTask (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, System.String taskName) [0x00084] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4029/b49471af/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/TasksManager.cs:165
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.539] [Exception] ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.InvalidOperationException: No suitable component archive found.
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.539] [Exception] at Xamarin.Web.Installer.TasksManager.DetectComponents () [0x00097] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4029/b49471af/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/TasksManager.cs:297 <---
[2017-01-12 10:08:54.648] [Debug] Detection complete on the introduction page, determining the next step.
```

Comment: I just received a similar error on El Capitan

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac is 7.x while Xamarin Studio is 6.x, and they have different Xamarin bits and dependencies. Thus, "I have both Xamarin Studio Community Edition installed and Android Studio installed, so all required components should be satisfied" is not true. Like one of the answers says you should report as a bug and wait for a solution from the vendor.

Comment: Well this is partially true, since most of dependencies will be satisfied if you first install Android Studio keeping in mind that you need API levels 15,19 and 21. Tools and platforms tools and builds tools are automatically installed.    Of course Mono, and its dependencies must be updated to the latest version used by the visual studio for mac installer (that is actually the xamarin studio installer with minor changes ;)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem earlier and fixed it. I'm assuming those that have the issue went to the Visual Studio for Mac web page and clicked the download button which downloads the installer. When this fails you're presented with a list of Android SDK requirements which are the following:

- Android SDK Tools
- Android SDK Platform-tools
- Android SDK Build-tools
- Android API 15
- Android API 19
- Android API 21

Open the SDK Manager and install them. The binary for launching my installation of the SDK Manager is the following:

- /Users/Matt/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/tools/android

Obviously substitute 'Matt' in the path above for whatever your username is. Once these are installed you need to download the following:

- https://dl.xamarin.com/VsMac/VisualStudioForMac-Preview1-7.0.0.347.dmg

This is the full download and not the 20MB installer you get on the main site. Click the file and install and you should be good to go. Anyhow, that worked for me :-)

Comment: This solution works, thank you! I keep it open in order to have more info about this issue and to find a general solution starting from the VS downloader packager (the installer).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to replicate this behavior locally, and have filed [Bug 51529](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=51529) in the Xamarin bug tracking system.

Comment: Thanks a lot this will help to get a fix soon.